# How to filter an array in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am getting the following as the response of an API,

```
[
    {
        "profileName": "indoor",
        "frequencies": [
            {
                "frequency": "200",
                "L": 120,
                "R": 150
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "profileName": "outdoor",
        "frequencies": [
            {
                "frequency": "200",
                "L": 120,
                "R": 150
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to filter this result based on `profileName`, need to access the `frequency`, `L`, and `R` and I want to show these in labels, I don't know how to filter the result. How to do that?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and of course show a minimal example code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You need to map to some Decodable Model, and then you can use .filter on that array of models to check your conditions

Comment: Fundamentally, you just have an array of dictionaries. You're trying to get the 3 values nested within them. If you had just one of the dictionaries, how would you do that? And once you've done that, you can just use `map` on the array of dictionaries to get all those nested values in the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.create Codable structs to convert your JSON to swift

```
struct ResponseModel: Codable {
   let profileName: String
   let frequencies: [Frequency]
}

struct Frequency: Codable {
   let frequency: String
   let l, r: Int

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case frequency
    case l = "L"
    case r = "R"
}
```

}

2.convert

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

let response = try! decoder.decode(ResponseModel.self, from: jsonData)
```

3.an example of filtering data

```
let indoorFrequencies = response.filter{$0.profileName == "indoor"}.map{$0.frequencies}
```